# How to "delete" GetHashCode of my class

Tags: c#, hash, equality

I have a struct that I want to use equality syntax to compare its instance. But I'm 100% sure there is no scenario I will put them in a hashing structure. As recommended, whenever equality is override, GetHashCode need to be override as well. So my question is how do I tell the compiler that I don't need this method in any circumstances? Like the "=delete" in C++11.

And I don't want to override because I really don't know how to implement. There is a double field in my struct. In my equality check, a tolerance is allowed. How should I implement GetHashCode under this circumstance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetHashCode` is public virtual method of `Object` which is the root class for all objects in the CLR system. So, no you cannot "delete" the method. You can override it, and throw an exception if you do not want users to call it, but you cannot "remove" it in the sense you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

For mutable reference types, *you should only override if*:

- You can compute the hash code from fields that are not mutable.
- You can ensure that the hash code of a mutable object does not change while the object is contained in a collection that relies on its hash code.

Otherwise, you should not modify the object while it's stored in a hash table.

For implementing your own `GetHashCode` method, when dealing with multiple fields, one way to generate a has code is to combine these fields using `XOR`.

[Documentation on Object.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) <-- There's a lot of good information for you there if you haven't already looked it over.